Is there a recommended format to store a large amount of text which is both human readable and organized and also usable by a RAG-LLM?
Use case:
I have tons of text, files, and notes spread across various cloud storage accounts and devices. I want to find a format to store all my information and data in one place. I tend to delete stuff when there is too much to organize and manage, but if I had an efficient mental workflow where I knew what format to put stuff in, I could probably save a lot more info without an undesirable cognitive load of endless editing and organizing.
Pain point:
I don’t know what format to use. Manually editing things to “be neater” is too much effort. I don’t know if I should keep documents as they are, or break them into smaller modular facts or pieces of information.
Considered alternatives:
YAML? JSON? A relational database? I use Obsidian.
If all my info is in one place, like a readable, queryable database, I can easily find what I’m looking for, and I can easily attach my personal knowledge base or knowledge graph to an LLM for RAG, too.


Is there a recommended format to store a large amount of text which is both human readable and organized and also usable by a RAG-LLM?

No, because the RAG-LLM will have some data ingestion script to ingest the texts, so any format that is supported by the data ingestion script is ok for the human to use.
